# Not properly closed sql command

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this code:

```
def_where:=def_where||'  TO_CHAR(date_of_input,''MM'') like '''||'to_char(date_of_input,''MM'')=nvl(:DSP_month,to_char(date_of_input,''MM''))'||'%'  ||'to_char(date_of_input,''RRRR'')=nvl(:DSP_year,to_char(date_of_input,''RRRR''))'||'%''';
```

and i m getting error sql command not properly ended.

Comment: after the first like may you need one '

Comment: and at the end you have 2 more ' i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def_where` suggest, that this is part of dynamically built query, condition of `where` clause. But produced string makes no sense, it should be something like:

```
declare 
    def_where varchar2(32767) := '';
begin
    def_where  :=  def_where 
        || ' to_char(date_of_input, ''MM'') '
        || ' = nvl(:DSP_month, to_char(date_of_input, ''MM'')) and' 
        || ' to_char(date_of_input, ''RRRR'') '
        || ' = nvl(:DSP_year, to_char(date_of_input, ''RRRR''))';

  dbms_output.put_line(def_where);

end;
```

Look what you got from `dbms_output`, correct this syntax if needed. You could also rewrite your string to get this:

```
(extract(month from date_of_input) = :DSP_month or :DSP_month is null) and 
(extract(year  from date_of_input) = :DSP_year  or :DSP_year  is null)
```